# How do I use the CSS Adjacent sibling selector in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

When using Angular components with styleUrl and separate stylesheet files, every CSS selector will be scoped to it's component in the output.

Now let's say I want to define a rule, that when a article is followed by another specific component, the later one needs a margin-top. In this case, when a article-card is followed by a article-group element.

The markup would be something like this:

```
<article-group
    [topArticlesOnly]="true"
    [articles]="homepage.top | slice:0:6">
</article-group>
<article-card
    *ngFor="let article of homepage.top | slice:0:6"
    [article]="article">
</article-card>
```

Both will contain a div with a specific class you'll see in the following examples.

I tried something like this:

```
[article-card] + [article-group] {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

article-card + article-group {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

And like this:

```
.article-card + .article-group {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

But both doesn't work because the browser output of the markup will be like this when Angular compiles it:

```
<div _ngcontent-c3="">
    <article-card _ngcontent-c3="" _nghost-c4="" ng-reflect-article="[object Object]" ng-reflect-show-image-only="true">
        <article _ngcontent-c4="" class="article-card article-card--top-article article-card--image-only" ng-reflect-klass="article-card"
            ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
        </article>
    </article-card>
    <article-group _ngcontent-c3="" _nghost-c5="" ng-reflect-articles="[object Object],[object Object" ng-reflect-top-articles-only="true">
        <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="article-group article-group--top">

        </div>
    </article-group>
</div>
```

And the outputting CSS scoped like this:

```
[article-card][_ngcontent-c5]+ [article-group][_ngcontent-c5] {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

article-card[_ngcontent-c5] + article-group[_ngcontent-c5] {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Maybe it needs some combination of :host-context or :host, but even then I never got my selectors to apply to the correct context.

**So is there a way to use the Adjacent Sibling CSS Selector in Angular stylesheets?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using view encapsulation.none so you don't get those extra [_ngcontent-c5]

```
import {
  Component, ViewEncapsulation
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-something',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Comment: Any disadvantages with this method?

Comment: By default angular is emulating the shadow dom so that all your styles in a component don't leak out to other places providing encapsulation.  But on a case by case, like this you might want to turn it off.

Comment: I accept this answer for the moment since it seems to be the only solution to my exact question.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of the `:host` selector to refer to the "current" component.
Like so:

```css
article-card + :host {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add classes, like this:

```
<article-group class="article-group"
    [topArticlesOnly]="true"
    [articles]="homepage.top | slice:0:6">
</article-group>

<article-card class="article-card"
    *ngFor="let article of homepage.top | slice:0:6"
    [article]="article">
</article-card>
```

and

```
.article-card + .article-group {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't be the right way building components. The whole benefit of having the class used at one place, inside the component, will be lost.